# How to iterate using pointers to structures?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have written a small program in which I use a pointer to keep track of array of structures. I have a few questions regarding the same:

1) In `main()`, I iterate using the macro "COUNT". How can I iterate using the `arr_struct` or `arr_struct[i]` in place of COUNT? Is it possible to derive the number of entries in `arr_struct` from `arr_struct`?

2) Is the following statement OK if I do not wish to assign a value to `place`?

`(*as)[i].name = strdup("foo");
 (*as)[i].place = NULL;
 (*as)[i].n = 1234;`

3) Do you see any wrong programming practice, bug, or memory (allocation and free) related issues in the following code?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct info_s {
    char *name;
    char *place;
    int n;
} info_t;

#define COUNT 2

static void
get_data (info_t **as)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        info_t *tmp = (info_t *)realloc(*as, (i + 1) * sizeof(info_t));
        if (tmp != NULL) {
            *as = tmp;

            (*as)[i].name = strdup("foo");
            (*as)[i].place = strdup("bar");
            (*as)[i].n = 1234;
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    info_t *arr_struct = NULL;
    int i;

    get_data(&arr_struct);

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        printf("[%d].name:%s,\t", i, arr_struct[i].name);
        printf("[%d].place:%s,\t", i, arr_struct[i].place);
        printf("[%d].n:%d\n", i, arr_struct[i].n);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        free(arr_struct[i].name);
        free(arr_struct[i].place);
    }
    free(arr_struct);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In principle can not know the size of  `arr_struct` by having its head pointer, but you can make your `get_data` method inserting some element with specific content to play as an ending pattern, then you can iterate your pointer until reaching that pattern so you know it is the last element.

Answer (score 2):

1) add an 'end' member to your structure set to Zero normally, add another instance of that structure in get_data, with that member set to -1 and then loop up to it in your main.

2) That will work in get_data but blow up the printf (and your free). You'd have to check for it. Better to always set it to "". If it means something special to be null, it would be clearer from a 'be nice to the programmer' standpoint to add another member. (yes it takes more memory. Your computer has a lot of that.)

3) Looks pretty good to me. I would have forgotten to free the strings. General advice - realloc will work for <1000 items but if you have 100s of k, use a linked list. It will also solve some of the other problems you speak of (of course, you won't have index access, but for this sample you don't demonstrate a need).

good luck!

Comment: 1) I see.
2) So if I add a `NULL` check before accessing the variable in `printf` and before calling `free` that would be OK for `(*as)[i].place = NULL;` ?
3) In my actual case (not in this program), `realloc` will be called more than 5000 times (for more than 5000 entries). Do you still suggest linked list?

Comment: 2) Yes you are right 3) Yes, but there is a special technique to solve the problem with `realloc()`

Comment: Yes, you'd be alright if you did that. You'd have to comment the heck out of it. If you just used strdup(""); it would put in empty. Then if this were a special case, you could check for it without having to check if things will blow up. If "" is a valid place and NULL is 'no place' I'd still recommend adding include<stdbool.h> and to the structure: bool HasNoPlace; - set to false by default.

Comment: @Sergey _"I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of how to solve the problem with `realloc()` that this margin is too narrow to contain"_  How can you leave us hanging like that?

Comment: @Sergey Is the technique so special that it's not worth mentioning? ;-)

Comment: @FastAl, Any comments for my 3rd point..
"3) In my actual case (not in this program), realloc will be called more than 5000 times (for more than 5000 entries). Do you still suggest linked list?"

Comment: That's small enough for this to work esp. with the small structures. Cost of re-writing would not be justified. If you know linked lists and it solves the problem (iteration only) and you have a lot of data, use it to solve the problem.

Comment: I added another answer with a description of the technique. I do not know how to fit a block of code inside comments

Answer (score 2):

Since `realloc()` is a too "expensive" function, the standard aproach is as follows.

```
const int capacity = 100; // for example
    
static void
get_data (info_t **as)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        info_t *tmp = *as;
        if (i % capacity == 0)
            tmp = (info_t *)realloc(*as, capacity * (i/capacity + 1) * sizeof(info_t));
        if (tmp != NULL) {
            *as = tmp;

            (*as)[i].name = strdup("foo");
            (*as)[i].place = strdup("bar");
            (*as)[i].n = 1234;
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for the non-optimal code in this example. I made minimal changes to the source code solely for demonstration.

## UPDATE

More accurate example

```
const int capacity = 100; // for example

static void
get_data (info_t **as)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {       
        if (i % capacity == 0)
            info_t *tmp = (info_t *)realloc(*as, capacity * (i/capacity + 1) * sizeof(info_t));
            if (tmp != NULL) {
                *as = tmp;
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        (*as)[i].name = strdup("foo");
        (*as)[i].place = strdup("bar");
        (*as)[i].n = 1234;
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I'm just about to allocate the 5000th entry (for example the last entry), it will actually allocate memory for the size of 5100 entries. It will always allocate more space than you actually will consume and need.
Won't it?
Could you also pls highlight the optimization done in UPDATE's example?

Comment: Yes. You will always allocate more memory than you need. But... If you need exact 5000 you will allocate exact 5000 because the last value of `i` will be `4999`. So `i/100` will be `49` and you will allocate exact 5000.

Comment: You can change the capacity value to whatever you think is reasonable.

Comment: I have observed this technique in many programming languages ​​and in many libraries. In C ++, the `std::vector` object is similarly designed. True, for `std::vector` the value of the capacity does not mean the size of the memory increase, but the total size of the captured memory.

Comment: Chunk size can be adaptive. For example, you can increase the memory by 10% each time instead of increasing it by 100 elements.

Comment: As for optimization ... Before UPDATE, we do `* as = tmp` and` tmp = * as` at each iteration. After UPDATE, we do it 100 times less.

Comment: Before UPDATE we ignore allocation errors and do nothing. After UPDATE we print the error message and finished the program

Comment: I suspect that I used the wrong name for the variable. “Capacity” should be “chunk_capacity” or “chunk_size”.

Comment: You can read more about `capacity` and architecture of `std::vector` for example here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/

Comment: I believe that borrowing standard solutions is good practice. Even if this solution does not suit you, you will understand how to adapt it to your circumstances.

Comment: Also note that when using linked lists, you will also consume more memory than you need, since the pointer to the next item also takes up space.

Comment: You can also call `reallocate()` after the loop to reduce the memory size to the exact value.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I do agree with your point of "borrowing standard solutions". And that's the reason I'm exploring this more.

Comment: It's just that if the total number of entries is 5001 then last call to realloc will allocate memory for 5100 entries i.e. 99 more than the required. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right... But you can call `realloc(*as, 5001 * sizeof(info_t))` just before return from `get_data()`... If you really need it.

Comment: Clever optimization @Sergey glad you mentioned it! I totally get it and it would mitigate some problems (plus your heap would be thanking you if it had a will)